# Custom login checks (Grails Spring Security)

Tags: security, spring, grails

In our system, users are never deleted from the database. What we do is to anonymize their information and add a timestamp in the date_delete column.

How do I configure Grails Spring Security to check that a user is not "soft deleted" from the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement the `UserDetailsService` interface and within the `loadUserByUsername` method you can customize the way users are located.

Refer to the [Custom UserDetailsService](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html) within the plugin documentation for more information.